# Radomly add or subract 1;

Tags: c++, random

I am writing a program in which I came to the problem of having to randomly add or subtract 1 from a number.  I would like some input on the simplest way to do this.  The program is in C++ by the way.  Thanks.

Comment: What sort of probability do you want for the "randomly add" vs "randomly subtract", and do you also want a "randomly don't add or subtract"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <cstdlib>
...
if(rand()%2)a++;
else a--;
```

That's not very hard to do. Its simple trick.

Answer (score 3):

```
a += (rand()*1.0/RAND_MAX) < 0.5 ? -1 : 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a random integer, check it's parity. If it's even, decide to add 1, otherwise subtract 1.

Answer (score 0):

Generate your random number from 0-9 and store it in a variable. Then check if it's even or odd, if even add 1 to your number, else subtract:

```
int yourNumber = 1150;
int rand = rand() % 10;

If(rand % 2 = 0)
    yourNumber += 1;
else
    yourNumber -= 1;
```